# Struts2 action namespace & Requested URL not found on tomcat in linux server

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, tomcat7, web.xml

I have developed web application using Struts2 + Hibernate + Java7+ Mysql 5.5 and its working successfully in my local windows server.

I have deployed this (local working) code under public_html folder in production server. Production environment is Linux + Tomcat 7 + JDK 7 based server.

While accessing the example.com it displaying the index page only without listening struts2 action.

If I am trying to login or register into the application it says **“Not Found The requested URL /myactionname was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.”**

It should be look up ***myactionname*** in struts-default.xml file, and then process the business code, then its return to the jsp page to render view of this application. I don’t know why this not working in my application. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: How do you deploy your war on the production server ? Do you have ssh credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the `public_html` folder of this production server? If I remember correctly, isn't this the public folder for any LAMP based sites hosting servers which are mapped with the local Apache server ?

For Tomcat7 deployments, it is required that you place your war ( or folder ) inside the `webapps` folder located at `$Tomcat_dir$/webapps`.

Also make sure from the logs that your application is getting properly deployed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My hosting provider has mapped settings & port number to point public_html folder directly. So whatever Jsp or classes I can place in this folder directly. Tomcat will take care this for deployment.
Actually I am getting home page of website without using struts2 action. If used struts2action it displaying not found error.

Comment: `I am getting home page of website without using struts2 action` Does this mean that you use a URL something like `http://host:port/yourWarName/some/folder/theJSP.jsp`, and it is entertaining the JSP ?

Comment: If you hit http://host:port/projectname/ it will call the welcome.jsp file. Because I have make entry to show welcome.jsp as welcome file. In welcome.jsp page, <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=homepage"> added. So its automcatically calls the action – homepage in struts-default.xml file and then displaying success page. But it’s not working right now. Without listening anything their displaying index.jsp file.

Comment: I see. Can you take a look into the logs of the application ? see if any exceptions is being thrown

Comment: Nope. I can find only the server startup information. I have added sop in action to test whether the action is called or not. Its not displaying in log file.

Comment: `I can find only the server startup information.` There isn't anything in the logs related to your application being deployed /